# Measures of correlation / influence for predictors with bounded outcome

Tags: multiple-regression, bounds, partial-correlation, interval-censoring

I'm doing a systematic review of epidemic models that project "the % reduction in incidence ($Y$) after K years" given a particular simulated intervention. The models include various assumptions ($X$), and I'm trying to determine which assumptions have the largest influence on projected $Y$. For simplicity we can assume all assumptions $X$ are binary variables.

My first thought was to use partial correlation coefficients based on linear regression $Y = BX$, but the outcome is bounded on 0-100%. Then, I thought maybe logistic regression, but that seems wrong since $Y$ is not binary.

So, what would be an appropriate measure of correlation / influence for predictor variables $X$ on a continuous but bounded outcome $Y$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'd use a GLM with an offset, at least as a first pass. Which programming language do you write?

Comment: Thanks @joehoeller Can you provide a reference for the offset approach? How does this solve the bounding problem?  R or Python are fine.

Comment: Did you see the answer below?

Answer (score 0):

For GLM, offset is used when modeling a rate, and is assumed to have a known slope. Since we're looking at the incidence (a rate) after K years (time period), a Poisson with the denominator of the rate (target population) is offset by log, making it's slope equal to 1 as a covariate / feature.

For example, if you were using R, assuming your variables are n (surviving number), N (initial number), ttt (a factor/categorical variable specifying treatment group), you would use:

```
glm(n/N~ttt, family=binomial, weights=N) 

glm(n/N~ttt, family=quasibinomial, weights=N) 

glm(n~ttt+offset(log(N)), family=poisson)

MASS::glm.nb(n~ttt+offset(log(N)))
```

Link: https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat504/node/168/